# Storing a bitfield in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Is there a way to store a bitfield of 940 bits in a SQLite3 Database in a way that meets my needs?

I need to be able to query to check if the bit at a given position in the bitfield is set.

Comment: why is this considered a bad question? sqlite3 has no datatype for Bitfields?

Comment: I edited your question to dissuade close votes. How it was worded seemed on the surface to invite opinions instead of answers. However, you have a set requirement here.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to work around this limitation that doesn't involve 940 indexes, but I'm not coming up with any.

Comment: The closest I can get is using integer fields and doing a bitwise `&` on them. However, it's unknown if it can handle 904-bit integers.

Comment: no 2^940 = 9.293856e+282

Comment: one could use 940/64 = 15 integers to store this but this is also no good solution, but might be more efficient than to store 960 indices.

Comment: What is the meaning of those bits? How many bits are set? It might be a better idea to normalize this.

Comment: For most of the fields nearly all are set. What do mean by normalize? They represent days in several years. If a bit is set on that specific day something happens.